# How to get distinct records applying '$in' while query in Mongo DB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

there are duplicates records for each id in MongoDB. I am querying multiple ids using $in.

I want the unique record for each id.

Comment: Please show your code.  Did you first test your query in the mongo shell or a db tool like Robo3T (formerly known as Robomongo)?

Comment: I do know, How to query with $in query in MongoDB. but I have duplicate records against each id. when I am querying using $in, I get All records. I want unique records against each id or first record of each id.

Comment: Thinking about it, your question doesn't make sense. You said there are duplicate records for each id but you want the unique record for each id.  There is no unique record if each id has multiple records.  What are the values in `$in`? I first thought they are the ids of duplicate records but if that was the case you wouldn't need to query for duplicate records because you know them. I voted to close because it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You still need to show what you've tried (code and/or query).

Comment: I have documents in DB like : {id:1 topic:"a" sub_topic:"b"},{ id:1 topic:"a" sub_topic:"c"},{ id:2 topic:"e" sub_topic:"f"},{ id:2 topic:"f" sub_topic:"g"}, {id:2 topic:"f" sub_topic:"e}

Now , when I am querying 

db.topic.find(
   {
      id: { $in: [ '1', '2'] }
   }
);

I am getting all records . This is not what I want .

I want only 2 records having id=1 and id=2.

Comment: take a look at the aggregation framework

Answer (score -1):

Imo you should look at mongodb aggregation framework, or its implementation in java.
Please provide json example of what you're expecting, for more precise answer
If you just want distinct id's, use distinct function
db.collection.distinct("id")
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.